# WordPress - Save Dropdown Selected Option and Show it on the Frontend

Tags: wordpress, http-post, categories

I am fighting with this for days. I am trying to add a custom dropdown with options when creating or editing a post category:

```
function changePostOrder(){
    ?> 
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="cat_page_title"><?php _e('Post Order'); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <select name="post_order" id="post_order">>
                <option value="" disabled selected> Order by </option>
                <option value="ASC" <?php selected( $options['foo'], 'ASC' ); ?>>Oldest</option>
                <option value="DESC" <?php selected( $options['foo'], 'DESC' ); ?>>Newest</option>

            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>    
    <?php

}
add_action ( 'edit_category_form_fields', 'changePostOrder');
```

So far, so good. However, I want to save the selected option, so that it displays the selected option on the frontend. But nothing happens:

```
function saveCategoryFields() {
    if ($_POST['post_order'] === 'Oldest')  {
        //do something and then update the field
        update_term_meta($_POST['tag_ID'], 'post_order', $_POST['post_order']); 
    }
}
add_action ( 'edited_category', 'saveCategoryFields');
```

I checked the codex and I think I should use [get_term_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/) to get the value, but I do not know how exactly to do that. Basically, I need something similar to this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8736/add-custom-field-to-category) but for a dropdown list. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a function called [add_meta_box()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/). Use this to wrap your form-field and it will format the $_POST argument when you submit the page.

You hook into add_meta_boxes to call a function that will invoke add_meta_box at which time you can pass it some arguments.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'yourname_create_metabox' );

public function yourname_create_metabox(){
    if(is_admin()){

        add_meta_box("a-meta-box-name", "Hi! I am a meta box",  "your_metabox_markup_function", "", "", "");
    }
}
```

You wrap your form in that your_metabox function and make sure to add a nonce field for security:

```
public function your_metabox_markup_function(){
    global $post;

    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_order');
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__),'yourname_post_class_nonce');

// your form here

}
```

Then you can save the form:

```
public function yourname_save_metabox($post_id){


    if(!isset($_POST['yourname_post_class_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['yourname_post_class_nonce'],basename(__FILE__)))return $post_id;


    if(isset( $_POST['post_order'] )){
        // save however you need
    }       
}
add_action( 'save_post',  'yourname_save_metabox', 10);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can i integrate this code to the edit_category_form_fields hook? I want to add additional field to the default category form in the wordpress dashboard, I do not want to make a new form. Can you show it with my code?

Comment: I need the same functionality as this but as a dropdown list: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8736/add-custom-field-to-category